# UITextField - Posicionar o cursor durante a edição

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

Estou fazendo um tratamento para edição de UITextFied para formatar o texto como decimal com separadores decimais e milhares. Minha dúvida é como posicionar o cursor sempre no canto direito do text field?

Grato

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isso através do código:

```
[self.fieldValor setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
```

Ou pelo *Interface Builder*, tem essa propriedade:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Paulo, não seria bem isso. A ideia é não reposicionar o cursor durante a digitação.